# Pintool and itrace

Tags: windows, executable, intel-pin

I met a problem when using pintool and itrace,

I use pintool to execute a HelloWorld.exe demo program

```
pin -t itrace.dll -- HelloWorld.exe
```

However, the generated "itrace.out" indicate no eips for user code

like this:

```
0x77e52996
0x77e52998
0x77e52999
0x77e5299a
0x77e5299b
0x77e5299c
0x77e2dd42
0x77e2dd45
0x77e2dd4c
0x77e2dd53
0x77e2dd6d
0x77e23c50
0x77e23c56
0x77e23c59
0x77e23c5b
0x77e23c5d
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.